# Xcode 9 - How to remember the latest simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9

I select and run the app on the `iPhone 8` simulator. Then, I quit and reopen Xcode. The `iPhone 8 Plus` is selected by default. How to remember the latest simulator on Xcode 9? My project is using CocoaPods.

Answer (score 12):

Even newly created projects seem to exhibit this behavior.  To resolve this, here is the hack I've found that appears to correct the problem.  Unfortunately you need to do this for every project:

1. Choose Edit Scheme: CMD + <
2. Under Run -> Info: Change the **Build Configuration** from "Debug" to
   "Release". Then change it back to "Debug"
3. Press **Close**
4. Change to the simulator you'd like to use, and close project.

Upon opening the project again, it should remember what simulator you had it left at.  Hope this helps you as well!

Comment: Ultimately all you need to do is tweak anything in the scheme so that it updates, and then the simulator problem goes away.